# Determine user scroll vs JavaScript scrollTop change

Tags: javascript

How can I determine if a scroll event was caused by my own animation, or it was caused by a user's scroll?

---

I have a scrollable area, which acts like a CV control knob, where the user can scroll and directly map to a DOM element's size, left, and top

If a scroll event ends inside specific bounds, I want to "snap" to a nearby position, with a granular tween that modifies the same scrollable area's scrollTop.

While this transition is occurring, I want any user scroll to immediately override the animation, so that the user regains control

---

I feel like I'm very close to a solution, and I noticed that my usecase involves floating point increments, where a user scroll will only increase by full integers. I'm not sure if this is useful, and it feels like a hack to abuse, but I'm really looking for ANY WAY that I can discriminate between a user scrollTop change, and my animation's scrollTop change

Comment: If you are using a framework (jQuery in particular) you could pass an argument to the `.trigger()` call. This call would be present in code-made calls, but absent from event calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to keep track of the delta scroll distance added and what the scrollTop **should** be.

If the browser polls for scrollTop and emits a scroll event, you need to compare that scrollTop with your intended addition, or whatever scrollTop is supposed to be. You can also pursue listening for "wheel" rather than scroll

---

The biggest problem for me was that scrollTop cannot have floating point numbers, and setting scrollTop to 150.999 is the same as setting 150, so I recommend Math.round() beforehand, and checking the scroll `Math.abs(event.target.scrollTop - myScrollTop) < 1` or some similar comparison, since myScrollTop is still the correct, floating point (non-integer) number

---

Also worth mentioning is that zooming and changing the CSS reference pixel (`window.devicePixelRatio`) seems to affect scrollTop ingestion or emission

Right now, my scroll behavior breaks if I use CMD+ or CMD-, but I will deal with this shortly

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck at something I was doing in my project and I needed to detect whether user is scrolling or is it that our code that is scrolling.I used a global variable `myVar` which changes its value depending on scroll events.
**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/fqav6j89/)**

Here is the code.

```js
var myVar = false;
$("#button").click(function() {
  myVar = true;
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#bottom").offset().top
  }, 2000);
});
$(window).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event) {
  myVar = false;
});
$(document).scroll(function() {
  console.log('Scroll initiated by ' + (myVar == true ? "user" : "browser"));
});
```

```css
div:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span> hello there </span>
<br/>
<div id="button"> click here to go down </div>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="bottom"> just sitting </div>
```